# Can not parse xml from SOAP

Tags: javascript, html, xml, soap

I have got a XML as response from SOAP service using JS. But i can't show it in HTML. 
Here is my JS Code.

```
 function renderXML(xmlDoc) {
                  var i;
                  var list="<ul class='ui-listview'> "; 
                  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Table");
                  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
                    list += "<li class='ui-li-static'>" +
                    x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                    "</li> " ;
                  }
                  list += "</ul>";
                  document.getElementById("ws_data").innerHTML = list;
                }
```

I got this XML as response. 
http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountries

It shows

```
app.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
```

on this line

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Table");
```

But if i send a hard coded xml to that function it works fine! And shows in html.

```
var data= jQuery.parseXML("<NewDataSet> <Table> <Name>Afghanistan, Islamic State of</Name> </Table> <Table> <Name>Albania</Name> </Table> <Table> <Name>Algeria</Name> </Table> <Table> <Name>American Samoa</Name> </Table> </NewDataSet> ");


renderXML(data);
```

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web service returns an XML in this format:

```
<string>XML as TEXT</string>
```

So you need to parse the `XML as TEXT` in order to get an XML document. Please chek out this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/q20w39f8/

Besides, after inspecting the server response headers, there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, this means that the server doesn't allow cross-origin access. Since you make a cross-origin HTTP request, your request will be rejected by the browser following the Same-origin policy:

> The same-origin policy restricts how a document or script loaded from
>   one origin can interact with a resource from another origin. It is a
>   critical security mechanism for isolating potentially malicious
>   documents.

In short, you **CAN'T** make an ajax request to that web service.

PS: in my demo, I used a CORS proxy: https://crossorigin.me/

Comment: Not working ...it shows app.js (42) :TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName')

Comment: I am using Jquery 1.9.1...is it the problem ?

Comment: No...i used XMLHTTPRequest